# faster boolean from string conversion

Tags: javascript, boolean

For numbers you can do `+"10"` instead of `Number("10")` which is a chunk faster. Is there a way to do this for boolean from a string?.

Comment: `Boolean("false")` is `true`, btw.

Comment: @FelixLoether That certainly was an oversight on my part. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's silly to use a regexp. If you really only want to match the string `'true'` and don't care about case sensitivity, just compare against that string:

```
function parseBoolean(s)
{
    return s === 'true';
}
```

I suppose if I were really going to play "fill in the blank" with you, I'd answer:

```
+"10" is to Number("10") as !!"true" is to Boolean("true")
```

since `Boolean(x)` only returns `false` when `x` is a falsy value, that is, when `x ∊ {null, undefined, false, 0, ''}`.

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution indeed: http://jsperf.com/string-to-boolean

Comment: Added `s === 'true'` in a function since function call overhead might be non-negligible: http://jsperf.com/string-to-boolean/2. Interestingly, on my machine, your Object Map approach was fastest.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I'll probably end up using your variation of biziclops answer from your jsperf, thx for the speedtest references. +1

Answer (score 1):

If matching all case variants of the word `true` is the requirement, I believe using a regex is the quickest, eg:

```
/^true$/i.match(input)
```

Comment: This is only quick if you're going for case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Some not-so-good and evil solutions:

```
window.toBool = {'false':false,'true':true};
toBool['false'] === false

eval('false') === false // don't ever do this!

JSON.parse('false')
```

Comment: First one deffo not-so-good, since `toBool[42]` is `undefined`.

Comment: These are negative examples :)

Comment: @biziclop You certainly had something going with the toBool idea. I would have sent you the points, but the prepend of `window` doesn't sit too well with some best-practices I've read recently. +1